# Pourquoi on a mis "il fallait" dans cette phrase?

Tags: temps-grammatical, passé-composé, imparfait, concordance-des-temps

> Le jour du départ, on est partis à l'aube parce qu'**il fallait**
> prendre une correspondance.

Est-ce qu'il est possible de mettre "**il a fallu**" dans cette phrase?

Answer (score 3):

Non. Si « on est partis » et « il a fallu » sont tous les deux conjugués au passé simple ou au passé composé, ce sont deux évènements ponctuels. « On est partis » se passe forcément avant « prendre une correspondance ». Mais le rapport de causalité entre « prendre une correspondance » va dans l'autre sens : on savait qu'il faudrait prendre une correspondance avant le moment de partir. Donc « il fallait prendre une correspondance » n'est pas un évènement ponctuel, c'est une affirmation qui couvre un intervalle de temps qui va d'avant le départ au moment de prendre la correspondance. Puisque l'affirmation s'applique à un intervalle de temps, on utilise l'imparfait.

On pourrait utiliser le passé simple s'il n'y avait pas cette relation de causalité. Par exemple : « Nous avons dû prendre une correspondance, et nous sommes arrivés la nuit tombée. »

Même avec la relation de causalité, on peut considérer « prendre une correspondance » comme un évènement ponctuel. Mais dans ce cas, la concordance des temps impose un temps différent : les deux évènements « partir » et « prendre une correspondance » se passent à des moments différents, donc il faut qu'un des deux soit à un temps qui n'est pas le temps du discours. On peut ainsi dire : « on est partis à l'aube parce qu'il faudrait prendre une correspondance », avec un conditionnel qui sert ici de futur dans un discours passé. Cette phrase est grammaticalement correcte, mais je la trouve un peu étrange. Il me paraît plus naturel de dire : « on est partis à l'aube parce qu'on savait qu'il faudrait prendre une correspondance » — et on voit là l'imparfait revenir, puisque « on savait » a une durée.

Si l'évènement qui est hors du temps du discours était dans le passé, on utiliserait un plus-que-parfait : « Le jour du départ, nous avons pris une correspondance, et pour cela nous avions dû partir à l'aube ».